# Full remote access to Android device

Tags: android, remote-access

**Background:**
I'm looking for an app that lets me control my Android device from my computer.

Sadly, any attempt at Googling this, only yields results for using the Android device as a remote control.

I've been using Pushbullet for some time, which lets me see Android notifications as popups on my computer. It also lets me do some basic stuff, like reply to text messages when they pop up, but this is very limited.

**Additional info:**

I'm perfectly OK with using a web interface to access the phone. I'm also familiar with VNC, if that's an option.

Huge bonus for any app that lets me control the device using the computer's mouse to simulate taps and swipes.

**Android version:** 4.4.2

**Price range:** Any

**Security:** Any commonly accepted encryption. For VNC alternatives, this is probably a non-issue.

EDIT: What I'm looking for is full remote access. That is, seeing the full screen of my phone, with my computer's mouse simulating touch on the Android device.

Comment: If it is not full remote you are looking for but an app that lets you read/write messages, get notified if someone calls, find your phone etc. [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) might be an option.

Answer (score 8):

Teamviewer also features remote control of your phone. You'll need [Teamviewer Quicksupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) on your phone and the ordinary [Teamviewer application](http://www.teamviewer.com) on your computer. It allows full control as well as direct access to various settings like WLan profile, app-manager, file exchange and more. Some won't like that it needs to contact a server hosted and owned by the company behind Teamviewer negotiating the connection. Once the connection is established data is only exchanged between your computer and your phone. Of course it also offers the other way round (control computer with phone).

Edit: I've just noticed that it is necessary for some of the other solutions to have your device at hand to get the connection details. The partnerlist of Teamviewer also works for Quickconnect devices. If your mobile is listed on the partnerlist and runs the Quickconnect app you can connect via doubleclick without having to know the devices ID or some URL etc.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty useful. I didn't know TeamViewer worked both ways. +1 sir, and welcome to SoftwareRecs

Comment: +1 Nice to know! I somehow never thought to go from pc to android, just the other way around :)

Comment: Does that solution require the Android device to opt in manually (each time) with a user acknowledging the remote connection that is being made/requested? I wouldn't mind a one time acknowledgement on install of app. But having a user acknowledge on device each time defeats being able to autonomously remotely manage "test" devices.

Comment: The new version 11 promotes that feature, see [https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/currentversion.aspx](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/currentversion.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to access Android from another Android device using Teamviewer? If yes, how?

Comment: I never needed that functionality so I haven't tried it yet. On their [website](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile-apps/) they say you can. You'd need Teamviewer QS or Host on the target device and Teamviewer: Remote Control on the other. Then connect the same way you would access any other device, via ID or partnerlist.

Comment: Is teamviewer considered reasonably secure these days? I heard they were victim to a big hack a few years back, I can't remember the details, might have been a download of all their users credentials

Comment: I'm no security expert. Teamviewer said that users were using same credentials for various services resulting in the hack. I can't tell if that's true but I'm still using it and never had trouble doing so. Anyone else with more insight on Teamviewers trustworthiness?

Answer (score 6):

Blame Google for not finding my site (but first make sure it really didn't :)

For a list of candidates, I might refer you to [Full remote device management](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement#group_807). Most likely candidates matching your request (which I have personally used) include:

### [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

This is probably the most famous candidate. It requires an app to be installed on your Android device. Start that app and its service, and it presents you with the data needed to connect it. These you enter in your web browser, and will be presented with a "remote desktop":

[image: Airdroid App] [image: Airdroid Desktop]
<sup>*Airdroid* app (left) and desktop (right); source: [cio.com](http://www.cio.com/article/2371416/)/[t3n](http://t3n.de/news/airdroid-2-erschienen-groses-460815/); click images for larger variants</sup>

As the screenshots show, you'll get real desktop feeling – and access to many details including call logs, files, create screenshots, see device stats, and have a shared clipboard. For more details, please refer to the linked articles (and the app's page on Play, of course). Moreover, the first mentioned page (on my site) links to additional material.

### [3CX DroidDesktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm)

This app is pretty similar to above described *Airdroid:* You'll need to install an app, and get a "remote desktop":

[image: 3CX App] [image: 3CX Desktop]
<sup>*3CX DroidDesktop* app and desktop (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Features are, as indicated, pretty much comparable – so it's mainly a question of preference which of the two to chose; provided of course that's matching your wishes. Again, for alternative candidates, let me refer you to [my site](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid) – where you hopefully also find matching candidates for your other needs. Other than most market sites, this uses "real life categories", and links additional information to each app whenever possible.

Comment: AirDroid seems great at first glance. I purchased a month of premium, so hopefully it'll suit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Just remembered that you've also mentioned VNC. When interested in that kind of solution, you might also wish to take a look at another one of my lists, [Remote Droid 2: Control your Droid from your Computer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid) :) But Airdroid is pretty easy to deal with – and has the big advantage of not requiring a specific desktop software, any browser suffices – so it can be used wherever you are.

Comment: Is it possible to access Android from another Android device using AirDroid or 3CX? If yes, how?

Comment: @TominJacob Different question. As you've left this comment on other answers as well, I'd suggest [asking a separate question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic. But basically: As *AirDroid* runs a web server to deal with access from the outside, I don't see why you couldn't use another Android device with a web browser to access it.

Answer (score 4):

[Androidscreencast](https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast) allows you to see, and to a certain level control, your Android device.

- View your Android device's screen
- Use your mouse to "touch" the screen (rooted devices only)
- Use your keyboard to type (rooted devices only)

It can be installed on any Java-capable platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc). You will need ADB for this to work. Help on that on our sister site for Android Enthusiasts: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

It is open source.

[image: Androidscreencast]

Answer (score 4):

[**mobizen**](https://www.mobizen.com/?locale=en)

Completely control your Android from computer, anywhere!, Either plugged in via `USB` or wirelessly over `WiFi` or your `mobile data carrier`

Mobizen unleashes this awesomeness! There’s plenty more goodies here like recording the screen without root

- Completely mirror your Android to computer screen to PC or Mac over Mobile Data, WiFi or USB!
- Completely control every aspect of your phone or tablet remotely!
- Screen record without root!
- Transfer files with ease!
- Easy to setup!

[image]

Just see this video  : - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdepDY3ynxg

---

Note : IMO,To completely mirror your android this one is the best

Comment: Just tried it for 5 minutes, and it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly and zero-cost. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to access Android from another Android device using Mobizen? If yes, how?

Comment: It was claimed this is free, but the Mobizen service costs $3/month or $24 per year, maybe that service isn't essential to run it? play.google says the app is incompatible with my device (Samsung S6 running Android 7.0) when it is suppose to support Android >=4.0 So not sure what my phone is missing?

Comment: /\ clarification: The free version only provides local tethered use. for use on external networks the pro version for $3/month or $24 per year is required. Also for Samsung owners the Samsung specific version must be found on play.google

Answer (score 3):

Let me recommend [aPuppet](https://apuppet.org) which works on Android 7 and above. This project has been developed by our team especially for self-hosted remote support.

It is completely open source, the code is available on GitHub ([Android app](https://github.com/h-mdm/apuppet-android) and [server](https://github.com/h-mdm/apuppet-server)).

The app doesn't require adb or rooting for screen mirroring and remote control. It isn't sensitive to the device model and Android build, and can work even on AOSP.

The server is deployed on premises, on Ubuntu Linux, and can work behind a NAT or even in a private network.

Answer (score 1):

I have three android TV PCs at home. I use them as thin clients against a windows server machine, and they work excellent! But, how do I remote into the android devices to keep them updated and backed up? I spent a lot of time finding a good solution for this. I also remote into my galaxy Note 3 sometimes.

What I use on each android device is vnc_server  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schumi.vncs . It has some issues, but for the most part works very well. I give each android device a static IP address either through wifi or ethernet. There are others similar. Each seems to be made from the same code base that was made public a few years back. Install this, work through the issues, and it will do what you want.

On the PC side to get into the android devices I use UltraVNC  http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html . I had to do trial and error to get everything right, but it does do what I want. I tried several VNC software packages until I settled on this one.

Another piece of software I put on the android devices is Webkey  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey . This gives me an alternate means of control should vnc_server get hammed up. It has good functionality and is very reliable. The android device is accessed via web browser. Depending on what you want to do, Webkey itself may be enough. The way the menu overlays the display is a little cheesy, but other than it's good.

I tried Airdroid but ultimately could not find much use for it and was disappointed. I paid for it, too!

I love TeamViewer. There's a TeamViewer client for android I use to see my work machine, and it's like I'm sitting right there! Excellent piece of software. For thin client in my house I use Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta. But there is no TeamViewer compliment allowing you to get into the android device. I had TeamViewer Quicksupport on the android devices, but uninstalled it.

Where you say:

> Sadly, any attempt at Googling this, only yields results for using the Android device as a remote control.

This is very true and was extremely frustrating. But I did finally get what I want.

Comment: The VNC server app disappeared from Playstore it seems. Some alternatives are in my list of [VNC-Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_671). Unfortunately, most are either outdated or expensive … And Webkey nowadays only works via Cloud :(

Answer (score 1):

[scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#scrcpy-v124) (screen copy):

> This application provides display and control of Android devices connected via USB or over TCP/IP. It does not require any *root* access. It works on GNU/Linux, Windows and macOS.

Pros include:

- Free, and open source.
- You don't need to install anything on your phone, just enable [ADB debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#Enabling).
- Doesn't need a rooted device.
- Works on Linux, Windows, Mac.
- Supports recording.
- Supports mirroring with Android device screen off.
- Supports copy-paste in both directions.
- Supports Android device as a webcam (V4L2) (Linux-only).
- Supports physical keyboard simulation (HID)
  physical mouse simulation (HID)

... Among many other [features](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#features).

If you're on Linux it should be in your distro's repositories. If you're on Windows you can install it with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [scoop](https://scoop.sh/).

A possible con is it requires Android 5, which is above the version requested, but as this was asked 7 years ago I'm assuming that's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you SideSync it use VNC feature .it also have a nice theme and style and more easier to use     but the problems:
 _You can't ring your phone with media and system sounds but with sonneries like in clock alarm and sound settings
_You must open sydesinc in your phone first then you can connect your pc and the phone
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.sidesync30

Comment: I tried SideSync, I thought maybe if Samsung developed it, it would be well designed... but it only works if the mobile device is tethered by USB or on the same wifi network. I don't really understand why you would want a remote access app which only works in the same building, bit pointless ??

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to remotely support or control Android at scale, perhaps as part of a service team:

Check out [Bomgar](https://www.bomgar.com/remote-support/platforms/android). It supports remote viewing and file for most Android and iOS devices, and it has remote **control** for Samsung, HTC, and Dell hardware.

The appliance can be hosted on premise so it's great from a security / compliance perspective. Not cheap, but it's a critical component of our support infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

[AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads) is free for personal use and is very easy to use - just enter an ID from one device on the other one to connect to it and then confirm the remote control request. Unattended access is also supported, although on Android 10+ it requires [additional configuration](https://support.anydesk.com/AnyDesk_on_Android#Screenrecording_Dialog_.28Android_10.2B.29) over USB.

Supports a wide range of mobile and desktop platforms, including Windows (a small 3.5MB self-contained `.exe`), Linux (`.deb` package), macOS, and even some rare ones like Raspberry Pi and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is MMECS Software ADB WebUI. It allows full control of any android device from a web interface, doesn't require rooted devices, and is the originator of codeless test creation. It also has many built-in utilities for aiding in creating test scenarios. Check it out on youtube channel mmecs.sqatools for additional information.

Comment: Does it allow access to MY device, or is it an emulator?

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this product?  If so, our community requires you add a full disclosure within your answer.