# Android app to fully access Android Device from another Android Device

Tags: gratis, android, remote-access

I already see this question ([Full remote access to Android device](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/full-remote-access-to-android-device)) and the answers. But am not looking for PC to Android access. I want to access my Android Device from another android device.

The features of the app should be:

- It should be able to open apps.
- It don't need root access.
- Ability to transfer files(optional).
- It can be used over Wifi and Mobile Data.
- It should be free.

When we use Teamviewer for PC to PC access we can do all things. I need this app somewhat like that. I tried Airdroid, but it has 200 MB limit.

Comment: "use over mobile data" might be the limiting factor here, depending on your carrier (which might block some "incoming traffic"). And if carrier doesn't limit anything, there's no difference on using it via WiFi or mobile data :) That said, and file transfer being optional: Are VNC solutions acceptable? There are client and server apps available. Other popular solutions (e.g. AirDroid) would work, too, but lack the "able to open apps" feature AFAIK.

Comment: @Izzy Is it possible with VNC? Both of my devices are not in the same network.

Comment: Can you `ping` one device from the other? Nothing like this will work if they cannot reach each other (except when using some "intermediate service" both devices connect to actively, as e.g. *TeamViewer* does).

Comment: @Izzy Can you explain a little more on how to ping one device from the other?

Comment: [Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) using a terminal app (or `adb shell`). Of yourse you could also use a [network tool](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_374) like [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing) which includes "ping". But you will need to know the IP address of the remote device to ping it. Using *Fing* on both devices will make finding it out easy ;)

Comment: @Izzy Ok. If that is possible, then what shall I do next?

Comment: Check with a [VNC-Server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_671) on the device you wish to access, and a [VNC client](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_655) on the other one?

Comment: @Izzy Can you suggest a good VNC Server for android?

Comment: If I could, I had written an answer :) I'm not using any, so: No, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy I too don't know. Thats why I posted my question here.