# App to remotely access Android from other Android device without having to press "allow" each time

Tags: android, remote-access

This is similar to the question "[Full remote access to Android device](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/full-remote-access-to-android-device)".

I also am looking for an app to control (or possibly just view) my Android device remotely. I need to view live the display of the device. However, I have two additional requirements.

1. The viewing device is also an Android device. AirDroid running in a web browser on the device does not work properly on mobile.
2. The device which is being viewed will be in my home without anyone physically accessing it, and I will be out traveling. Therefore, no one will be able to press "allow" or anything like that on the screen. Everything has to be set up before I leave the house.

I have root, Xposed framework, Magisk, etc.

I can run pretty much any Android version, whatever works. I prefer 8.1.

Comment: What's wrong with TeamViewer? Anything with "VNC" in the name should do the job.

Comment: @Mawg TeamViewer requires that one presses "allow" on the device each time before remote access can start. The device will be at home with no one to press "allow."

Comment: OIC. I don't use TeamViewer. I do use TightVNC on PCs and the home PC doesn't need any interaction. Have a look in Google play for anything with VNC in the title. If you find a good one, please post an answer here, to help others in future

Comment: You can probably use Tasker to detect and press Allow button in Teamviewer. Something like this https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/5svgni/respond_to_popup_screen_audio_warning_how/